# Why axios doesn't remove elements from my variable?

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to delete all completed tasks in my ToDo list. 
In the code, I assign all completed tasks to the variable "completed". Next, I want to delete completed tasks from the server using axios.

```
removeItems = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let completed = [];
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
            todos: prevState.todos.filter(todo => {
                if (todo.completed == true) {
                    completed.push(todo)
                }
                return !todo.completed;
            })
        }
    })
    console.log(completed);
    const remove = completed.map(async (todo) => {
        await Axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/todoes_destroy/{id}/`)
    })
}
```

Comment: Looks like your url isn't correctly interpolated. You're missing the $ before {id}. await Axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/todoes_destroy/${id}`)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you, I added $ before {id}. But now I can see the message "'id' is not defined  no-undef" :/

Comment: I changed ${id} to ${todo.id} so there is no error message "'id' is not defined no-undef". But it still don't work.

Comment: Have you looked server side? Is anything logged?

Comment: Server side is ok...

Comment: What does that mean? Is the API call logged? Is data deleted? You said it doesn't work but what does not work?

Comment: Data is not deleted from the database.

Comment: Does the delete query reach the back end? What's in your browser network tab? Is there any error in the logs on the back end? "It doesn't work" is not going to help us fix your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to check things to give you that answers. I'm new to coding :(

Comment: I changed the code. Now it should delete data from server. I have to figure out how to update the state. 
`    removeItems = async (event) => {
               event.preventDefault();

               const completed = this.state.todos.filter(todo => {
                   return todo.completed
               });

                // console.log(completed);
               const remove = completed.map( async (todo) => {
                   return todo
                   await Axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/todoes_destroy/${todo.id}/`)
               }
           ) `

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code and now it works. This is the solution,

```
removeItems = async (event) => {
               event.preventDefault();
               const completed = this.state.todos.filter(todo => {
                   return todo.completed
               });

               const remove = completed.map( async (todo) => {
                       console.log(todo);
                       await Axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/todoes_destroy/${todo.id}/`)
                   }
               )

                const {data} = await Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/todoes_read/', {
                 })
                this.setState({todos : data})

    }
```